# Adding an ActionScript eventListener that takes the whole sprite

Tags: actionscript, sprite, addeventlistener

I have a very simple constructor in ActionScript as the following:

```
public function ButtonTest() {
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, browseFiles);
}
```

My problem is that when I open the SWF file itself, the window is not full size and the whole area responds to the mouse click. If I expand the window to full size, a margin of like 200 pixels on the left is not clickable. I hope I make some sense.

The issue is that I had the .SWF file in a  in my HTML code, and when I make it small, it seems that only the center of the SWF file is clickable.

I hope someone can please help me.

Thank you,
Rudy

Comment: Maybe to make more sense, I want to point out that my issue is that the whole SWF file should respond to the mouse click. Unfortunately, not the whole area responds to the mouse click depending on the size of the window. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `stage.scaleMode` to `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`, that will allow you to read the actual size of the movie so you can stretch the button over that entire area.

Comment: Cool, then you should click the accept button (check mark) next to this post, that's how the site works :)